# LWUIT TextArea doesn't catch touch events

Tags: java-me, checkbox, touch, lwuit, lwuit-textarea

I have made a `Container` compound by a `TextArea` and a `CheckBox`. In my app, I create so many of this "`Containers`" and add to each `TextArea` inside of them an `ActionListener` (implemented by the class). Something like this:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i<20;i++){
 MyContainer c = new MyContainer();
 TextArea t = c.getTextArea();
 t.addActionListener(this);
}
```

I want the `TextArea` to catch the event and if it is pressed put the `CheckBox` checked or unchecked. It works fine in non-touch devices and simulators but in the touch devices or emulators, the `TextArea` doesn't catch the event. I tried to put the `TextArea`as the lead component of the `Container` but it doesn't works because `Container` doesn't have an `addActionListener` method.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly you are trying to create a compound component assembled from multiple different components to act like a single component. In LWUIT/Codename One this is called a [Lead Component](http://codenameone.blogspot.com/2011/01/lwuit-resource-editor-tutorial-part-10.html), the attached post is mostly about the resource editor but the concepts apply to manual coding as well. 
Just set the "checkbox" as your lead and everything should work.

You can code this manually by deriving and overriding but you will there are small edge cases like the change of style states (focused/pressed state etc.)

Answer (score 0):

It is better that you `derive` the `TextArea` class for the `getTextArea()` method. Then in this class implement the `pointerReleased` method : code the action performed in the normal way in it.